# Checking which Font is compatible for maximum browsers

Tags: interface-design, designers, web-fonts

Wanted to know about if Public sans is compatible for all browser or operating systems? and how i can check browser compatibility of any fonts?

Comment: Public Sans is available as a free web font via Google Fonts, which are supported by all relevant browsers on all relevant platforms. As Scott’s answer mentions, though, it’s not pre-installed on _any_ platform. So what do you mean by “compatible”? Web fonts are perfectly compatible with virtually all browsers these days, but they do still require pulling in the font from an external source, which IT departments may disable globally on company machines for security reasons, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Public Sans is **not** a default font on **any** operating system. So no, it is *not* "compatible" in itself and would require an `@font-face` declaration and/or a link to a repository to use. For a font to be "optimally compatible" it needs to installed, by default, by the operating system on *all* platforms.

If you want the most compatible fonts, you should check what is installed by operating systems and compare.

For example MacOS installs [**these fonts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_macOS).
Windows installs [**these fonts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows).
Linux Unbutu installs [**fonts listed on this page**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts).

If you simply search for "best compatible fonts for web sites". You will find articles such as [**THIS**](https://www.guru99.com/web-safe-fonts-html-css.html) which essentially compare the font lists for you and point out common fonts.

Common fonts I like to use are:

- Arial
- Courier
- New Times New Roman
- Georgia
- Helvetica
- Verdana

This list hasn't really changed in more than 20 years.